# How to use glGenTextures

Tags: opengl, haskell

In C I would do the following:

```
GLuint a;
glGenTextures(1, &a);
```

The type of `glGenTextures` in Haskell is:

```
GLsizei -> Ptr GLuint -> IO ()
```

How can I get a value of the type `Ptr GLuint` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the exact traslation of:

```
GLuint a;
glGenTextures(1, &a);
```

Is:

```
import Foreign.Marshal.Utils( with )

with a $ \dir_a -> glGenTextures 1 dir_a
```

If you need to pass an array, you can use `withArray` that get a list, and reserve and initilialize a buffer with that list. Also `allocaArray` can create for you the buffer without initialize it.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I'd like to point out that Haskell OpenGL bindings have a [high-level incarnation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/OpenGL) that [doesn't require the user to do manual memory management](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/OpenGL/2.4.0.1/doc/html/Graphics-Rendering-OpenGL-GL-Texturing-Objects.html).

In general, for any `Storable` type `a` you can obtain a block of memory sufficient to hold `n` elements of the said type with [`mallocArray`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Foreign-Marshal-Array.html#v%3amallocArray). The result of [`mallocArray`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Foreign-Marshal-Array.html#v%3amallocArray) has type `Ptr a`; like in C, you should use [`free`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Foreign-Marshal-Alloc.html#v%3afree) to free allocated memory space afterwards. You can also use [`allocaArray`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Foreign-Marshal-Array.html#v%3aallocaArray) to allocate memory temporarily (the equivalent of stack allocation in C). Here's how the `OpenGL` library [uses `allocaArray` in conjunction with `glGenTextures`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/OpenGL/2.4.0.1/doc/html/src/Graphics-Rendering-OpenGL-GL-Texturing-Objects.html):

```
   genObjectNames n =
      allocaArray n $ \buf -> do
        glGenTextures (fromIntegral n) buf
        fmap (map TextureObject) $ peekArray n buf
```

You can find more information on these topics [in the Haskell Wiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/FFI_Introduction).